# How to access the accumulator in javascript's reduce method as a object

Tags: javascript, object, reduce

I have been struggling with why this won't work. We start as a {}, then grab the first element of the split string array. If that object property exists, then increase the value by one. If not, then create the property and set the value to 1.  Any help would be really appreciated as I clearly am missing something about the reduce method.

```
const countCharacters = string => {
    return string.split('').reduce((total, element) => {
       if (total[element]) {
           return total[element] += 1;
       } else {return total[element] = 1}
    },{});
};
```

Comment: `return total[element] += 1;` makes `total` i nthe next iteration a number

Comment: @JaromandaX But shouldn't total[element] = 1 set the object key total[element] to 1, so we would have {objectkey: 1}?

Comment: yes, but it returns `1` - which means the second iteration `total === 1`, not `{objectkey: 1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `total` to be an Object in every iteration, you need to return the object from the previous iteration

Currently your code returns a Number = which isn't the Object you started with

Here's what happens with your code

```
'abca'.split('').reduce((total, element) => {
    if (total[element]) {
        return total[element] += 1;
    } else {
        return total[element] = 1;
    }
},{});
```

first iteration .. total = {}, element = 'a', return total.a = 1 (which returns 1)
second iteration .. total = 1, element = 'b' ...

So, you want something like:

```
const countCharacters = string => {
    return string.split('').reduce((total, element) => {
       if (total[element]) {
           total[element] += 1;
       } else {total[element] = 1}
       return total;
    },{});
};
```

Or, more succinctly

```
const countCharacters = string => string.split('').reduce((total, element) => {
    total[element] = (total[element] || 0) + 1;
    return total;
}, {});
```

Or, less succinctly, but a one liner

```
const countCharacters = string => string.split('').reduce((total, element) => (total[element] = (total[element] || 0) + 1, total), {});
```

Comment: Beautiful and thank you for the clear explanation with further examples. Just tested it and you nailed it. Thank you.  Do you mind tell me what you did in your second example?  I've never seen the use of (x||y) like that except for second if statements stating OR.  Does it have a name that I can google and learn more about?